# Column Formatting - HideSelection disable JSON Formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

After one week waiting for a Solution from Microsoft, I need to ask.
In About 5 SharePoint Online Tenants the JSON Formatting in Sharepoint lists stopped working.

I Debugged the Scenario and find, that the Variable "HideSelection" works like a Switch to Turn off/on the JSON Columnn Formatting. If "HideSelection" = "true" the JSON Formatting works. If the "HideSelection" = "false" everything is broke.

This Problem appears last week and before this I worked really well.

I searched the web for a solution or other victims of this but I don't find anything.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Can you please add the code you are using to your question? Also explain a bit what you are trying to do using JSON formatting.

Comment: Can you share one of the JSON sample you are using in your SharePoint lists? Also I might have reproduced this issue using the example given in this document: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting#multi-line-view-style But it is better that we double confirm before we jump to the conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Hey im Calle_1991 but now im using another Account.

U can reproduce it with these Steps.
On SharePoint Online

1. Create a new site/list in a targeted release tenant
2. Copy and paste the Multi-line view style sample from the link below into the JSON view formatter

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting#multi-line-view-style

3. Click Preview
4. Change the hideSelection value to false
5. Click Preview

with these steps you will see that the HideSelection Value works like a Switch.
I hope this helps.